# Rails Association: Teacher Student Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still learning to get creative with Rails and could use some guidance on best practice for the following Rails association:

I have three models, Teachers, Students, & Classes. Teachers can teach any numbers of classes, students can join any number of classes, and a class is only taught by one teacher but can have 1-5 students.

My first assumption is to use the follwing:

Class:
belongs_to teacher
has_many Students

Teachers:
has_many: students through => classes

Students:
has_many: teachers through => classes

I don't know if this is appropriate and I've seen suggestions for joining tables. Any guidance would be appreciated !

**Update: Given the feedback from the helpful users below, I'm suggesting the following solution. Can someone please verify this? Because a student can have many classes and belong to a class, and visa versa, I need two join tables**

```
class ClassRoomEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :students
 belongs_to :classrooms
end

class ClassRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :teacher
 has_many :students through: classroomenrollment 

end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :students :through => :classrooms
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :teachers :through => :classrooms
 has_many :classrooms through: classroomenrollment 
end
```

Comment: You missed `Student: has_many :classes`. Basically the relationship between Student and Class is HABTM. Everything else looks fine.

Comment: Thanks @Nitish. Would I have to add Teacher has_many :classes as well ?

Comment: And for the students, is has_many: classes replacing the has_many teachers through :classes relationship I added ?

Comment: Yes, you will also need `Teacher has_many :classrooms`. For students, what you currently have is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Class** is not a good name, **ClassRoom** is better

```
class ClassRoom < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :student # if I have well understand, this is the right association

  #some validations rules
  validates :<fieldname>, :<rule> => <value>, ...

  #callback like :before_save or :after_save, ....
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students :through => :classrooms, :depend => :destroy

  #some validations rules
  validates :<fieldname>, :<rule> => <value>, ...

  #callback like :before_save or :after_save, ....
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teachers :through => :classrooms, :depend => :destroy

  #some validations rules
  validates :<fieldname>, :<rule> => <value>, ...

  #callback like :before_save or :after_save, ....
end
```

With associations (has_many, has_one, belongs_to) joins through tables are automatically created. You can access all students of a teacher like

```
teacher.classrooms.first.students e.g.
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks @fellons ! Two questions. First why does a ClassRoom belong toa  student and not has_many students?

Also in you're example above, can I call student.classrooms.first.teacher (essentially the reverse of the above)

And finally, would I need to add any foreign indexes?

Comment: Actually, on second thought @fellons, I think I would need to make a join table between ClassRooms and students. In the above method there would be no way to access teacher.classroom.first.students

I think I would need to create a has_many :through relationship for classrooms and students as well. See my update

Comment: To implement the association :through between Teacher and Classroom and between Student and Classrooms there must will be a class (Classroom) which groups student_id and teacher_id (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html chapter. 4.2). Does not need to create indexes, as it joins between the ID fields are already indexed. The join is bidirectional (through the class Classroom): student.classrooms.first.teacher (or simply student.teachers) or teacher.students.

Comment: I understand but if Classroom is to have any other fields (i.e. room #, time, etc.) its better to make that a separate class as I did in my edited comment I believe.

Comment: To select the Students or Teachers of a particular Classroom, you can use two ways: (1) Create a classe ClassName has_many :classrooms and add belongs_to :classname at class Classroom (2) (even if it creates data redundancy: not recommended) Add a field :classname to the class Classroom and populate it every time with the name of a class. In this way, with a classroom.where (:classname => '<classname'>) you can extracts Students and/or Teachers of a given class name. This document may clarify your ideas on associations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.